# Spatial Error Model vs Conley standard errors

Tags: clustering, standard-error, clustered-standard-errors, spatial-correlation

What is the difference (pros and cons) of using an OLS with conley standard errors and a spatial error model? Is there a recommendation for when you should use one over the other?
Thanks!